# SSRS - two text fields that need to be combined to reach a total

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a simple query from a table that brings though items sold.

I have a field called ITEM.  Its output is either: TV, Radio or NULL.

In SSRS I've produced a summary table to give me totals of everything in this field, e.g.:

Tv - 1

Radio - 1

etc

I've set up a parameter query in SSRS:

```
Select distinct
isnull (a.ITEM,'NULL') AS 'ITEM'
from SALES AS A
```

and I refer to it in my main script:

```
and
ISNULL(a.ITEM, 'NULL') in (@ITEM)
```

However there is also a field called ITEM2 and I need to ensure anything in this field is included in the summary table mentioned above. I may have something like this in the output:

ITEM       ITEM2

TV          NULL

TV          RADIO

RADIO       TV

Giving me a total of:

TV - 3

Radio - 2

which I can't get at the moment because I'm only looking at ITEM, not ITEM2.

My question is - how can I include the items in ITEM2 in my summary total table? I've tried a couple of things to no avail.

Help appreciated massively - thanks.

Comment: If you're trying to include data from ITEM2 in your variable, something like this would work:
`select distinct
 isnull(a.ITEM, 'NULL') as SOME_ITEM
from
 SALES as a

union

select distinct
 isnull(a.ITEM2, 'NULL') as SOME_ITEM
from
 SALES as a`
But I'm not sure that's what you're asking help with?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Yes that's what I'm trying to do - and failing singularly. The UNION brings through exactly the same result and ignores the items in ITEM2, unfortunately. I basically need a simple table totting up items whether they're in ITEM or ITEM2.

Comment: Try `UNION ALL`

Comment: Thanks aduguid - I tried that and got the same output I'm afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the approach you've taken, you can do something like this:

```
declare @itemData table(
    ITEM varchar(16) not null /* size according to your needs */
)

insert into @itemData (ITEM)
    select
        isnull(a.ITEM, 'NULL') as SOME_ITEM
    from
        SALES as a

    union

    select
        isnull(a.ITEM2, 'NULL') as SOME_ITEM
    from
        SALES as a
```

Then instead of this:

```
isnull(a.ITEM, 'NULL') in (@ITEM)
```

try this:

```
isnull(a.ITEM, 'NULL') in (select item from @itemData)
```

I haven't tested that but see if it works.  Also, just an observation: It looks like you could accomplish this with an inner join and avoid using the variable altogether.  It *may* be better for performance too - just a thought.